# c++ socket recv function loop

Tags: c++, sockets

Im trying to send and receive 2 data back to back on tcp socket. Protocol is written below.

1. Client send data
2. On receiving the data on sever it sends back to client

Now using below client code I'm not able to get 2nd data and I think the 'Recv' function doing something wrong. Below is the code snippet.

```
int Recv(char* buffer, int size) 
{
  int total = 0, n = 0;
  while((n = ::recv(m_hSocket, buffer+total, size-total-1, 0)) > 0) 
  {
    total += n;
  }
  buffer[total] = 0;
  return total;
}

int SendAndReceiveData()
{
  //CStringA cstData :: this data getting filled by some other code. Ignore!

  //Send data
  char chSendBuff[256];
  memset(chSendBuff, 0, sizeof(chSendBuff));
  sprintf_s(chSendBuff, sizeof(chSendBuff), "%s", (LPCTSTR)cstData);
  send(m_hSocket, chSendBuff, (int)strlen(chSendBuff), 0);

  //Read response
  char chRecvBuff[256];
  memset(chRecvBuff, 0, sizeof(chRecvBuff));
  int iRet = Recv(chRecvBuff, 256);
}
```

Comment: You can use `char chSendBuff[256] = {};` to zero the array.

Comment: You do not need to zero out the buffer you receive into - it is a waste of time because you are going to overwrite that buffer anyway.

Comment: 'Recv' will not return until it has received 256 bytes or the connection closes.  Are you sending 256 bytes every time?  If not, does the client close the connection after sending less?  Also, 'memset(chSendBuff, 0, sizeof(chSendBuff));': cargo-cult.  You are loading the buffer with a guaranteed null-terminated string with sprintf_s() in the next line.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yeah.  Unfortunately, there are several client/server examples on the net with this rubbish and devs. have been slavishly copying the memset/bzero for decades, (often followed by ignoring the result returned by recv).

Answer (score 3):

Your receive function should look like this:

```
int receive(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{
    size_t toread = len;
    char  *bufptr = (char*) buf;

    while (toread > 0)
    {
        ssize_t rsz = recv(sockfd, bufptr, toread, flags);
        if (rsz <= 0)
            return rsz;  /* Error or other end closed connection */

        toread -= rsz;  /* Read less next time */
        bufptr += rsz;  /* Next buffer position to read into */
    }

    return len;
}
```