# i can't get full webpage

Tags: c, http

i wanted do http request but it doesnt download full page. only 7300bytes or less from any big webpage
if i try little webpage it download full
i tried different flags but still cant find my mistake

```
#define POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int sockfd;
char buf[25056];
int byte_count;

 memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
getaddrinfo("man7.org","80", &hints, &res);
sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
printf("Connecting...\n");
connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
printf("Connected!\n");
char *header = "GET /linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:         
man7.org\r\n\r\n";
send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
printf("GET Sent...\n");
//all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!

byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
printf("%.*s",byte_count,buf); // <-- give printf() the actual data size

return 0;
}
```

exec :

```
Connecting...
Connected!
GET Sent...
recv()'d 7300 bytes of data in buf     
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Dec 2017 16:04:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 18:41:34 GMT
ETag: "4d77-64f1-55f9c2f245380"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 25841
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230776/c-socket-recv-function-loop

Comment: regarding: `byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);`  a ethernet packet has a limited size, so this needs to be in a loop, where: always check the returned value, if <0 then an error occurred,  if 0 then all input received. if >0 then append the input data to the input buffer (this is usually done by manipulation of the second and third parameters so no separate copy needs to be performed.

Comment: always check the returned value from `socket()`, `connect()`, `send()`, `recv()` (etc) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, you have to `recv` repeatedly until the returned value is less or equal to zero. Also in such a simple case I'd recommend to send HTML 1.0 request to avoid chunked answers. Try the following code:

```
#define POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    char buf[65536];
    int n, byte_count;

    memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("man7.org","80", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    char *header = "GET /linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:man7.org\r\n\r\n";
    send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
    printf("GET Sent...\n");
//all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!

    byte_count = n = 0;
    do {
        byte_count += n;
        n = recv(sockfd,buf+byte_count,sizeof(buf)-byte_count,0);
    } while (n > 0);
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
    printf("%.*s",byte_count,buf); // <-- give printf() the actual data size

    return 0;
}
```